# nodejs https request with self certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https, certificate

I have this Curl command that works fine.

```
curl -vvv "https://<URL>:<port> --cert /etc/identity/client/certificates/client.pem --key /etc/identity/client/keys/client-key.pem --cacert /etc/identity/ca/cacerts.pem --capath /etc/identity/client/certificates
```

But when i try to translate from Curl syntax to NodeJs native(https) i got this error:

```
Http is failed. error: Error: write EPROTO 140452300855232:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

The nodeJs implementation looks like this:

Options:

```
options = {
  hostname:'url',
  path: 'path',
  method: 'GET',
  port: port,
  cert: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/identity/client/certificates/client.pem'), {encoding: 'utf-8'}],
  key: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/identity/client/keys/client-key.pem'), {encoding: 'utf-8'}],
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/identity/ca/cacerts.pem'), {encoding: 'utf-8'}]
};
```

Request:

```
https.request(options, res => {...do something})
```

The only thing i can think about is that the Curl command has 4 parameters(cert, key, cacert, capath) and on the node.https library i can pass only 3 parameters.

Any thoughts/Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: *"wrong version number"* - this has nothing with certificate validation. This kind of error happens for example if you connect to a system which does not actually speak HTTPS on the given port (but only HTTP).

Comment: Wired- because the same endpoint works via Curl

Comment: Same target port? Same system where nodejs and curl code run on? Maybe one has proxy settings and the other not? Might also be a firewall/DPI intercepting the traffic or some captive portal or so.

Comment: Yes. The curl I run via shell of the container. And the node is from the same container

Comment: If i use the HTTP protocol i get this error "Http is failed. error: Error: socket hang up"